# How to pass property from cellForRowAtIndexPath to a subClass of UIImage view

Tags: swift, uiimage, subclass

I am using Swift. I have a UIImage view in a auto-resizing custom table view cell that takes varying size images. Previously, I have been resizing the images before adding them to my UIImageView. But the images end up being poor quality.

To solve this, I though I could instead change the size of my UIImage view to match exactly the dimensions of the image (using ratios), then set the UIImage.contentMode to be AspectFill/Fit (it wouldn't matter) - and that way my image scaling would be taken care of for me.

When trying to resize the UIImage view in cellForRowAtIndexPath it doesn't work because autoLayout has not yet completed so all the dimensions get thrown out when the cell finally loads.

To solve this I am doing the following: I have subclassed UIImageView and plan on doing the resizing in layoutSubViews. My problem is: how can I pass into this subclass (each time it is initialised) the CGSize of the image it needs to adapt to?

When drawing the cell in my tableview I have the image that needs to load in that cell. But how do I get/pass that info to my UIImage subclass?

Thanks in advance.

PS. If you think I am going about this in entirely the wrong way, please feel free to say so. I'm fairly new to IOS dev.

Answer (score 0):

try imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit than you don't need to resize imageview.

If you still want to resize imageview than let me know I will provide solution for that aswell.

Thanks